# How to change variable color in vim solarized theme?

Tags: vim, colors, theme

I have just installed solarized theme for vim from https://github.com/altercation/vim-colors-solarized

But the problem for me is that the background stays black and I have the variable names in really dark blue color. Like so :

[image]

Does anyone know how to change that to ? (namely: where it is stored in the theme ?)

Comment: I think you must have either skipped an installation step or overlooked a prerequisite, such as a 256-color terminal. That's not Solarized. Not even close. (Speaking as one who has lived with this theme every weekday for about a year now.)

Comment: @WarrenYoung the problem was that I did not put `let g:solarized_termcolors=256` before `colorscheme solarized`

Answer (score 2):

`/usr/share/vim/vim73/colors/` contains themes for vim 7.3, but you can copy your scheme to `~/.vim/colors/` and edit it.

Answer (score 2):

You're not really using solarized.

It looks like you have the 16-color solarize theme selected in vim but your color pallet is still the default. You have two options:

1. Use the 256-color emulated pallet (see the README on how to do this).
2. Set your terminal colors to solarized colors.

If you're using `gnome-terminal` there's a color pallet setting utility bundled with Solarized. Execute it then restart your terminal.

If you're using something motif based (xterm, aterm, rxvt, etc) you'll need to set this in your `~/.Xdefaults` file (an example of which can be [found here](https://github.com/bahamat/dotfiles/blob/master/xmonad/Xdefaults).

If you're using Mac OS X Terminal.app you either need to set the colors by hand (using the included Solarized pallet helps) or use the 256-color emulated pallet.